How to fix Windows Update error: "Error encountered, We couldn't connect to the update service. We'll try again later, or you can check now ..."
I am running Windows 11 Pro 23H2 64-bit. Recently, when I try to run Windows Update, I get the following error:

I have tried all the "fixes" suggested here, here, and here, to no avail.
Specifically, I have attempted the following -

Disabling all third-party antivirus/antimalware software (in my case, MalwareBytes and CCCleaner. I ran full scans with both products first before disabling them, just to make sure a virus wasn't causing my problems).

Running the Windows Update Troubleshooter did not work

I tried resetting windows update components and restarting but this did not work either.

Changing my DNS settings to point to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for primary and secondary DNS servers, respectively.

Deleting everything inside the C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution after stopping wuauserv, cryptSvc, bits, and msiserver (and starting them again after rebooting my PC).

Running sfc /scannow (which indicated that there were no corrupted system files).

Running the batch file Reset_Reregister_Windows_Update_Components_for_Windows11.bat, which I downloaded from here.

I manually searched the Microsoft Update Catalog, downloaded the latest update, but it would not install, showing the error - This update is not applicable to your computer - but I checked and that is the exact update required for my system and windows version?

Tried an in-place upgrade but it failed because with a message saying that I am already using the latest version of windows 11.

While running the command line app as administrator, I also tried the following command DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth and it did not work.

I also tried deleting group policy and restarting and that did not work

Finally, I noticed that when I go to the advanced options menu in windows updates settings and turn on the retrieve updates from other microsoft products option, it has this strange behavior where when I leave the advanced options page and come back to it, the retrieve udpates from other microsoft products switches off again when I did not turn it off myself.


Not sure why this question was closed the last time I posted it, so please let me know why before you vote for it to be close so I can amend or improve it.

I have literally tried everything I could find on google to no avail. I attached the windows update log to see if anyone can help me here: WindowsUpdate.log

"I manually searched the Microsoft Update Catalog, downloaded the latest update" - Which update exactly? What build of Windows are you running?  Why is tags with Windows 11 Preview, that tag shouldn't be used, unless you're using a pre-RTM build of Windows 11.

"Tried an in-place upgrade but it failed because with a message saying that I am already using the latest version of windows 11." - That does not make sense.  The purpose of an in-place upgrade to the same build you are already using is to reinstall Windows.  Can you use the option to repair your installation through the Windows 11 only option with Windows Update?

Is the Windows Update Service running? Is the App Readiness service set to automatic?

@Ramhound The version of Windows I am running is 10.0.22361 build 22361, with a hardware abstraction layer version number of 10.22621.2506. I removed the windows-11-preview question tag - it was a typo. Yes, the Windows Update Service is running, and the App Readiness service is set to automatic. When I tried to repair my Windows installation, I only got an option to reset Windows - but no option to reinstall it and keep files. Also, the Windows update log I included at the end reports the following error code - 80072F8F - for which I have not yet found a working solution to resolve.

22361 is an Insider Preview build. I would first opt out of the Insider Preview builds and try to then upgrade to 24H2 opting into the Release Preview channel. Suspect your build is higher than the release channel for 23H2 which is the reason your not getting the option to keep your files. You’re also using a build that is over a year old hence your Windows Update errors. This is 24H2.

@Ramhound my system is x-64 based but it seems you sent an amd64-based upgrade ... can you direct me an x-64 based one?

I did? Every x64 processor is based off the x86 extension created by AMD. Windows and Linux for years as associated the 64-bit kernel with AMD and kept 32-bit associated with x86. Besides there is only one non-ARM iso for Windows 11 since a 32-bit version of Windows 11 does not exist. This has been the case for at least 2 decades.

@Ramhound The Windows update error is not resolved. Based on the link you provided, I upgraded my machine from version 23H2 to 24H2. The one issue that was resolved is, that when I toggle on the retrieve updates from other Microsoft products button in Advanced options for Windows update settings - it stays on instead of turning off by itself every time I leave the page and return to it. But the We couldn't connect to the update service error whenever I check for updates remains. The Windows update log I linked in my question reports an 80072F8F error code for the failed update attempts
